# Changing clock speed of STM32F779II

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I'm configuring the clock of the LCD which has a max clock of 30MHz as following. Plus I'm using the touch at I2C1, and USB at 48MHz.

The clearing and painting an image to the LCD is slow, and it's not that fast, also the operations that the CPU is using is really slow. I'm not sure what is configured wrong, or how do I configure the MCU to run at MAX Speed.

Here is the screenshot of the configuration:

[image]

Comment: You need to configure and use the PLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in the Pinout & Configuration, RCC, High Speed Clock (HSE) to Crystal/Ceramic Resonator (and make sure you have it in your schematic/dev board).

Than I get the following screen after setting I2C & USB and let it compute automatically the timing table:

[image]